# How to solve an equation with Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product

For positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, I have the following identity:

$$
C \circ [A (C \circ X)B] = C \circ Z
$$

How can I solve this equation for $X$?

Note: $C$ is a matrix with 1s and zeros.

Edit:

Is it correct to argue that

$A(C \circ X) B = Z$ so $C \circ X = A^{-1}ZB^{-1}$. However, $A^{-1}ZB^{-1}$ corresponds to a dense matrix which contradicts with $C \circ X$ term

Comment: If $C$ doesn't contain any zero, then we can write $A(C\circ X) B = Z/C$? In this case since $A$ and $B$ are invertible we would have $X = \big(A^{-1}(Z/C) B^{-1}\big)/C$. (The division is element-wise division)

Comment: @lizardfireman $C$ is a matrix with 1s and 0s. I'll update the question.

Comment: Since this is a system of linear equations, you may always reformulate it in the form of $M\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(C\circ Z)$ and solve it.

Comment: @user1551 I was thinking about this little while ago. But can't think of the structure of M

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult. Just isolate $x_{ij}$ on the LHS. That is, if the LHS is in the form of $x_{ij}P$ + terms that do not involve $x_{ij}$, then the $(i,j)$-th column of $M$ is $\operatorname{vec}(P)$.

Comment: @user1551 $Vec(C \circ [A(C \circ X)B]) = Vec(C) \circ Vec(A(C \circ X)B) = Vec(C) \circ (B^\top \otimes A)vec(C) \circ Vec(X)$

Answer (score 2):

You may rewrite the equation $C\circ[A(C\circ X)B]=C\circ Z$ as
$$
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))(B^T\otimes A)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))\operatorname{vec}(X)=\underbrace{\operatorname{vec}(C\circ Z)}_{=\,\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))\operatorname{vec}(Z)}
$$
and solve it, where $\operatorname{diag}(v)$ means a diagonal matrix using the vector $v$ as its main diagonal.

Comment: What is $E_{ij}$? What do you also mean by $(i, j)$-th column?

Comment: It is the standard notation for the matrix whose only nonzero element is a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position.

Comment: What do you mean by $(i, j)$th column of $M$ when $M$ is a matrix?

Comment: Since $C$ is a matrix of 1s and zeros, some columns of $M$ are zero. So, I don't think we can solve this problem

Comment: Alternatively, we can factor $C$ to get $C\circ [A(C\circ X)B - Z] = 0$. This sounds like we only need to look at $i, j$ such that $C_{ij} \neq 0$, and solve $[A(C\circ X)B - Z] = 0$ such that $[A(C\circ X)B - Z]_{ij}=0$. In terms of vectorized matrix notations: $B^{\top}\otimes A \text{vec}(C) \circ \text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(Z)$, for rows which $\text{vec}(C)_{m} \neq 0$.

Comment: @shani The $(i,j)$-th column is the one multiplied by $x_{ij}$. E.g. when $m=n=2$, $x_{12}$ is the third element in $\operatorname{vec}(X)$. Therefore the $(1,2)$-th column of $M$ means the third column. For general $m$ and $n$, the elements of $X$ in $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ are arranged in column-major order. Therefore $(i,j)$ is the $\big((j-1)m+i\big)$-th element in the set $\{(k,l):\ 1\le k\le m,\ 1\le l\le n\}$ of $mn$ pairs of indices.

Comment: @user1551 $C$ is a matrix of 1s and 0s. So $diag(vec(C))$ is not invertible and results overdetermined system, isn't it

Comment: @shani The diagonal matrix is not invertible, but the system is *under*-determined, not over-determined. Anyway, as lizardfireman wrote in a comment above, you may simply remove the zero rows and columns from LHS of the vectorised equation and remove the zero rows from the RHS of the equation to obtain a smaller system.

Comment: @user1551 Removed rows are free variables (which can take infinite possible values), right?

Comment: @shani Yes. If $c_{ij}=0$, then $x_{ij}$ is a free variable because it doesn't genuinely appear in the equation (because $(C\circ X)_{ij}=0$ regardless of the value of $x_{ij}$). The removal of zero elements in $C$ (or zero rows and columns in $\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(C))$ ***per se*** also does not affect the consistency of the system, because when $c_{ij}=0$, we have $(C\circ Z)_{ij}=0$ as well.

Comment: @user1551 So I used be able to come-up with a reduced system of equations which might have unique values for a subset of $x_{ij}$'s that corresponds to $c_{ij} \neq 0$.